# Can I enable Remote Disc on a computer that shipped with an optical drive?

Tags: finder, remote-disc

I replaced the optical drive in my 2009 MacBook Pro with an SSD drive. I have enabled CD & DVD Sharing on another computer (running OS X 10.7.5) on my local network and inserted a data CD, but Remote Disc doesn't show up in the Finder sidebar on the MacBook Pro (running OS X 10.8.2). I'm assuming this is because the machine originally shipped with an optical drive. Can I enable Remote Disc on the MBP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had to do this on an iMac with a failed optical drive before.

From http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2009/09/enable-remote-disc-drive-sharing-on-any-mac.html:

```
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser EnableODiskBrowsing -bool true
defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser ODSSupported -bool true
```

... then reboot, and hopefully the option will then show up in Finder > Preferences > Sidebar.

Comment: @SSteve Excellent!